# Como obter apenas um valor do Json usando request.get_data() Flask Python

Tags: python-2.7, flask, python-requests

Sou iniciante em Python e gostária de uma dica para obter apenas um valor do seguinte Json.

```
{
  "test1":"valortest1",
  "test2":"valortest2",
  "test3":"valortest3",
  "test1":"valortest1"
}
```

Uso para obter o json da seguinte forma no flask.
dado = request.get_data()

Recebo como retorno o arquivo completo ao printar a variável dado, porem gostaria de manipular melhor isso, realizando o print apenas do valortest2.

Qual seria a melhor forma de realizar esse processo?

Comment: dá para usar `request.form['test1']`

Answer (score 0):

Você pode acessar o valor através da chave diretamente:
O método get_json já faz a conversão de JSON para um [dicionario](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries).

```py
json = request.get_json()
valor2 = json['test2']
print(valor2)
```